# How to generate a Wavelet Matrix?

Tags: matrix, wavelet-analysis

The Wavelet Matrix, also called the [Haar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_matrix), is very useful. We can find some useful information in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveletMatrix.html) on how to generate it, but [this document](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HaarFunction.html) is too hard for me. From my reading of the Wiki page, maybe `KroneckerProduct` can be of help. Can anybody make it a custom function?

Comment: @Young Can generate this matrix?

Comment: Arndt's *Matters Computational* has a prolly more understandable discussion.

Comment: Yode, as it stands your question reads as a request for others to do your work. Perhaps you could at least make the question self-contained by including a definition of this matrix, its properties, and an example. You should also show what you have tried so far that hasn't worked for you.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm sorry.And thanks for your direction.It's a pity I cannot find a good regulation about this matrix up to now result in I don't know how to give the first try.If I have,I'll add it in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update-2:**

More compact version proposed by J. M. with the matrix normalized:

```
steps = 3; (*order = 2^step*)
h = Nest[Join[KroneckerProduct[#, {1, 1}], 
              KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[#]], {1, -1}]] &, {{1}}, steps];
Orthogonalize[h] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Update-1:**

Creates un-normalized Haar matrix for $\text{order} = 2^n$.

```
steps = 3; (*order = 2^step*)

h = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}; (*2x2*)
Do[
 hn = KroneckerProduct[h, {1, 1}];
 hi = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[h]], {1, -1}];
 h = Join[hn, hi]
 , (steps-1)]
h // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you useful answer.but my original intention is getting that Wavelet Matrix.:)

Comment: Thanks for your heavy work for me,which make me deeply move...

Comment: Just a little confusion.Cannot we build a any order haar matrix?

Comment: Slightly more compact: `Nest[Join[KroneckerProduct[#, {1, 1}], KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[#]], {1, -1}]] &, {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}, 2]`

Comment: @yode My understanding is that 2^n orders are standard and should be what you need.

Comment: If normalization is desired, `Orthogonalize[]` does it in one blow.